# combobox tostring() returns object instead of value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, visual-studio-2017

I want to retrieve the string value selected in a combo box and convert  into an integer, however the SelectedItem method always returns the name of the object. Other posts suggest to use the Content property of SelectedItem but it is not available to me in vs2017 using .net 4.6.1. Can someone help me get the value without parsing the string?

Here's the Xaml followed by the cs file:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Combo_BaudRate" SelectedValuePath="Content" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="120" Margin="112,81,0,0" 
          SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" 
          IsReadOnly="True" >

        <ComboBoxItem Content="1200" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="2400" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="4800" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="9600" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="38400" />

</ComboBox>


private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Selected_Port_Baudrate = Combo_BaudRate.SelectedItem.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `ComboBox_SelectionChanged`. When you hit the breakpoint at runtime, hover the mouse over `Combo_BaudRate.SelectedItem`. Observe what the type of that object is. In the debugger, expand it and examine its properties. You will find what you want.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem?view=netframework-4.6.1#System_Windows_Controls_Primitives_Selector_SelectedItem) on [`ComboBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox);k(VS.XamlEditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.6.1) return the first selected [`ComboBoxItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.comboboxitem?view=netframework-4.6.1).

You want to get the value of a property of the selected item, not the item itself. So you should use [`SelectedValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue?view=netframework--4.6.1#System_Windows_Controls_Primitives_Selector_SelectedValue) in conjunction with [`SelectedValuePath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath?view=netframework-4.6.1) to bind the property value and convert it to the appropriate type :

```
int selectedBaudRate = int.Parse(Combo_BaudRate.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

Note that the underlying type of `SelectedValue` is `string` because you specified the `ComboBoxItem` property `Content` as the `SelectedValuePath`.

**If you do not set both `SelectedValuePath` and `SelectedValue`, `SelectedValue` will contain the same object as `SelectedItem`.**

Comment: You're welcome. You may mark this answer as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it helped you.

Comment: @EdPlunkett That's why I mentionned `SelectedValuePath` at the end of the answer, as it is set in the given code sample. I'll make an edit to make it clearer.

Comment: You need to click on the grey checkmark on the left of the answer you want to accept, it should turn to green. [More infos](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/390775)